# get manager info from Outlook Address List vba

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm using the below code to open the Global Address List window to select a contact in the list.

For the contact that is selected, I'd like to get the Manager name as well. However, I can't seem to get it to work.

Any recommendations?

```
Private Sub accountManagerName_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Dim CDOSession, cdoAddressBook, olkRecipients, objAE

    On Error Resume Next
    Set CDOSession = CreateObject("MAPI.Session")
'   Change the name of your Outlook profile as needed.
    CDOSession.Logon "", "", False, False
    Set olkRecipients = CDOSession.AddressBook(, "Global Address List", 0, False)
    For Each objAE In olkRecipients
        accountManagerName.Text = objAE.name
        'ccManager.Caption = objAE.Manager.name
    Next
    Set olkRecipients = Nothing
    CDOSession.Logoff
    Set CDOSession = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: There is a `ManagerName` property in the `ContactItem` object.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: this is on an exchange server, i don't have any contact info hosted locally... will this still work? how would i implement your example? (code)

Comment: What is the object type of `objAE` in your code?  Run `Debug.Print TypeName(objAE)` to find this.  If it's a ContactItem, then you just need to use the objAE.ManagerName property to get the Manager's name.

Comment: it is a Recipient object...

Comment: Ahmad Zaher's posts [here](http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=6688) have a bit of code you might be able to use.  However, since you're on Exchange (instead of Outlook), I won't be able to help with testing.  Good luck!

Comment: You could also use Active Directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to figure it out!

simply had to convert the recipient object into an addressentry object and pull the manager info from there,
this can be done by using `objAE.addressEntry.Manager` too!

```
Private Sub accountManagerName_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    On Error Resume Next
    Set CDOSession = CreateObject("MAPI.Session")
'   Change the name of your Outlook profile as needed.
    CDOSession.Logon "", "", False, False
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Please ensure you have Outlook open.", , "ERROR"
    Set olkRecipients = CDOSession.AddressBook(, "Select Account Manager", 0, False)

    For Each objAE In olkRecipients
        accountManagerName.Text = objAE.name
        AMfullName = objAE.name

        'convert Recipient object to AddressEntry object using the recipient ID
        Set objAE2 = CDOSession.GetAddressEntry(objAE.ID)

        AMfirstName = objAE2.fields(18)
        AMlastName = objAE2.fields(22)
        AMmanagerName = objAE2.Manager

'        Debug.Print AMfirstName
'        Debug.Print AMlastName
'        Debug.Print AMmanagerName
    Next

    ccAMmanager.Caption = AMmanagerName
    ccUserManager.Caption = getName("mgrname")
    ccAMmanager.Activate

    Set olkRecipients = Nothing
    CDOSession.Logoff
    Set CDOSession = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of Outlook Object Model, use [AddressEntry.Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry.manager?view=outlook-pia) property.

CDO 1.21 does not expose address entry's manager, but you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and its [RDO](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) family of objects (it offers a complete replacement of the CDO 1.21 library and can run both under Outlook and the standalone version of MAPI) - it exposes the [RDOAddressEntry.Manager](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressEntry.htm) property.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but this excel sheet will be used by more than 1 person and i don't think i'll be allowed to install the library on all pcs....