# outlook vba: get the manager of user who runs script

Tags: vba, excel

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519230/get-manager-from-outlook-contacts-using-vba) and [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532871/get-manager-info-from-outlook-address-list-vba) is described how to get the Manager from an Outlook contact. However: I would like to get the Name and the Manager of the user that runs the script. How could I do this?
thx

Comment: What did you code so far? You can see in the linked examples that the "Name" (initial user) is already there. Also you have an example of how to get the manager. In other words: You found your answers, so where are you stuck on your implementation?

Answer (score 0):

This was easier than I thought.
Of course you should add checks for `Null`, but the functionality is:

```
Set appOL = New Outlook.Application
MsgBox appOL.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Manager
```